# How to display data from sql server dagtabase in android using HttpGet

Tags: java, android, json, http-get, android-webservice

I am developing android app and I am having problems getting data from the database and displaying it into my app using JSONObject and HttpGet. Please help me solve my error.

Error:

```
Value 1 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

ViewPatient Class:

```
public class ViewPatient extends Activity {

public static ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
HttpClient client;
private ArrayList<Group> expListItems;
public ExpandableListView expandableListView;
String user_name, password;
String URL = OpdLogin.URL;
String unm, pass;
String group_names[] = new String[100];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_patient);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    unm = bundle.getString("user_name");
    pass = bundle.getString("password");
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    expListItems = setStandardGroups();
    ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(ViewPatient.this, expListItems);
}

public ArrayList<Group> setStandardGroups() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url = OpdLogin.URL;
    ArrayList<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url + "patientdetails?");

    try {
        get.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        get.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json ");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
        ArrayList<Child> ch_list;

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String jkey = jobj.getString("key");
            group_names[i] = jkey;
            String jvalue = jobj.getString("value");
            JSONArray JArray = new JSONArray(jvalue);
            Group gru = new Group();
            gru.setFname(jkey);
            ch_list = new ArrayList<Child>();

            for (int j = 0; j < JArray.length(); j++) {
                Child ch = new Child();
                JSONObject Jobj = JArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String lname = Jobj.getString("last _name");
                String email = Jobj.getString("email");
                String state = Jobj.getString("state");
                String city = Jobj.getString("city");
                int mob = Jobj.getInt("mobileno");
                int age = Jobj.getInt("age");
                String gender = Jobj.getString("gender");

                ch.setLname(lname);
                ch.setEmail(email);
                ch.setState(state);
                ch.setCity(city);
                ch.setMobileno(mob);
                ch.setAge(age);
                ch.setGender(gender);
                ch_list.add(ch);
            }
            gru.setItems(ch_list);
            list.add((Group) gru);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("Error in Http", e.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
public static ArrayList<Group> expListItems;
public static ArrayList<Child> childList;
Group g = new Group();
Child c = new Child();
ViewPatient viewPatient = new ViewPatient();

public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> expListItems) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.expListItems = expListItems;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return expListItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Child> chList = expListItems.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return expListItems.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    childList = expListItems.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return childList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
    tv.setText(group.getFname());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflaterInfl = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflaterInfl.inflate(R.layout.view_patient_details,
                null);

    }
    TextView list = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    list.setText(child.getLname().toString());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

Group Class:

```
public class Group {

private String fname;
private String disease;
private int dob;
private ArrayList<Child> items;

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getDisease() {
    return disease;
}

public void setDisease(String disease) {
    this.disease = disease;
}

public int getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(int dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public ArrayList<Child> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<Child> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class Child {

private String lname;
private String email;
private String state;
private String city;
private int mobileno;
private int age;
private String gender;

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public int getMobileno() {
    return mobileno;
}

public void setMobileno(int mobileno) {
    this.mobileno = mobileno;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add in your question the Json you are receiving?

Comment: 1 is not a valid JSONArray and cannot be parsed as one. Try using JSONObject with the correct mnethods to retrieve the data.